# correct autolayout constraint for UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, xcode6, constraints

I have a button on my view that must be positioned in the top left corner throughout all different screen sizes, but proportionate to the margins and scaled accordingly. I had success in doing so with several other IB objects by using the aspect ratio, and X/Y Centering, but this button seems to not be complying. What constraints should I look to add?

Comment: What do you mean by 'scaled accordingly' ? A UIButton has a set `intrinsicContentSIze` property which will persist through different screen sizes and orientations.

Comment: oh ok i see, mine was set to place holder i don't know how. @pe60t0

Comment: thanks, but how should i get this unbutton to position itself proportionatley to the different screen sizes? @pe60t0

Comment: If it is a 'standard' UIButton you will only need to place `top` and `leading/left` constraints so it stays in the left corner on any screen size and orientation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'position itself proportionally" ? Do you want it to be in the top left corner or in the middle or somewhere else ?

Comment: well i mean depending on the screen size, when i placed certain constraints on it, on a 3.5 inch it would be totally out the screen, 4 inch barely on the screen, 4.7 in the right place. @pe60t0

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show a picture on where exactly you want the button to be placed ? From your question I infer that you want to put in the top left corner - which is fairly straightforward as I explained above.

Comment: yes i apologize you answer was suffice, it worked. and i had to toggle my intrinsic size option @pe60t0

Comment: Great. You can close this question or edit it in a way that the intrinsicContentSize answer does help solve a particular problem. Best.